# Rails ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This is my layout, all in the `authors_controller` and `Author` model.

`index.html.erb`

```
<div class="row">
<div id="author-index" class="col-md-5">
    <%= render 'index'%>
</div>

<div id="author-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"></div>
</div>
```

`_index.html.erb`

```
<div class="row">
<%= form_tag authors_path, :method => 'get', remote: true do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction]%>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort]%>

<p>
    <%= link_to "New Author", new_author_path, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary"%>

    Search for Author
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], onchange: "$(this).parent('form').submit();"%>
</p>
<% end %>
</div>

<div id="indexTable" class="row">
     #contains a table
</div>
```

My controller's show action:

```
    def index
    @authors = Author.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html{}
        format.js{}
    end
end
```

When I look at the log of my server, all should work fine

> Started GET "/authors?utf8=%E2%9C%93&direction=&sort=&search=Ali"
>
> Processing by AuthorsController#index as JS
>
> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "direction"=>"", "sort"=>"", "search"=>"Ali"}
>
> Author Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `authors`.* FROM `authors` WHERE (first_name LIKE '%Ali%' OR last_name LIKE '%Ali%') LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
>
> Rendered authors/_index.html.erb (2.3ms)
>
> Rendered authors/index.js.erb (3.2ms)
>
> Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

However the page does not change. The form worked fine when I do it without remote: true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `js.erb` template named `index` into authors views folder (app/views/authors/index.js.erb). This template should have the javascript code that you want to execute (will be sent and evaluated on the client side) when the Ajax call is performed. More or less:

```
$("#author-index").html("<%= j(render 'index').html_safe %>")
```

Notice the `format.js` in the `respond_to` block; that allows the controller to respond to your Ajax request.